# Removing Page Change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

so my only method I could figure of was this:
A 'pre-index' page came up with my fade in logo and text, it then after a few seconds faded out. After the contents on pre-index had faded out it redirected the user to the main page where I faded in the html.

The problem is, when the page goes from pre-index.php to ls.php it doesn't flow because it's changing page. The background disappears, the browser window is blank and then the next page is loaded. I don't want that inbetween moment.

Is it possible to put my code from pre-index into ls? Here is my code:

Pre-Index Page:

```
<body onload="preLoader()" background="images/blue.png">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="loader">
        <div id="pre_title">Server Name</div>
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Your Logo" id="loader_logo">
        <script>
            var delay = 6500;
            $('#pre_title').hide(0).delay(500).fadeIn(2000);
            $('#loader_logo').hide(0).delay(500).fadeIn(2000);
            $('#pre_title').delay(500).fadeOut(2000);
            $('#loader_logo').delay(500).fadeOut(2000);
            setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "ls.php"; }, delay );
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the page it loads after all of this (ls.php) This is only part as the page is quite big.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Loading Screen</title>
<link rel=StyleSheet href="styles/main.css" type="text/css" media=screen>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function preLoader() {
        $("html").hide(0).delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="preLoader()" background="images/blue.png">
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
        <div id="sv_title">Server Name</div>
        <div id="sv_subtitle">A Garry's Mod Server!</div>
    </div>
```